# How can I open port 21 on a Linux VM?

Tags: linux, ftp, firewall, centos, port-forwarding

I need to open port 21 on a Linux (CentOS 5) virtual machine I have. I have tried several Google solutions, but none are working. I was wondering if someone could tell me how to do this.

---

Below is the output of `netstat -tulpn`:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2208              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3576/hpiod          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:611                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3397/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3365/portmap        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3020/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3629/sendmail: acce 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2207              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3582/python         
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      3595/sshd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               3278/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:605                 0.0.0.0:*                               3397/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:608                 0.0.0.0:*                               3397/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353                0.0.0.0:*                               3729/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               3365/portmap        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57333               0.0.0.0:*                               3729/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               3020/cupsd          
udp        0      0 192.168.201.90:123          0.0.0.0:*                               3611/ntpd           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               3611/ntpd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               3611/ntpd           
udp        0      0 :::5353                     :::*                                    3729/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 :::52217                    :::*                                    3729/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 fe80::20c:29ff:fe66:123     :::*                                    3611/ntpd           
udp        0      0 ::1:123                     :::*                                    3611/ntpd           
udp        0      0 :::123                      :::*                                    3611/ntpd
```

---

And here is the output of `iptables -L -n`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't have an FTP server running on the machine I am trying to connect to.